# How to convert from System.Int32 to System.UInt16 in F#

Tags: .net, f#

Is there a better (shorter?) way than the following?

```
let cpucount = System.UInt16.Parse( reader.GetInt32(3).ToString() )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let i = uint16 42
```

See also

[MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353754(v=VS.100).aspx)

and the 'casts' section of

[What does this C# code look like in F#?](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!725.entry)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know F#, but you could write `Convert.ToUint16(reader.GetInt32(3))`.

**EDIT**: [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233220%28VS.100%29.aspx), you can cast by writing `uint16 reader.GetInt32(3)`.